# the site is up and running, but some pages get an exception: "Views/XXX/xxx.cshtml" was not found

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I execute the dotnet .dll command in the publish file, everything works, but put the publish file on iis or linux jexus, the site is up and running, but some pages get an exception: "Views/XXX/xxx.cshtml" was not found

I'm sure the problem is not the path

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a controller that actually points to that page?

```
    public ActionResult xxx()
    {
        return View();
    }
```